# Assigning heights dynamically, based on arithmetic series

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a kind of timeline with d3, and I noticed if some events are close on the timeline (within a few days of each other) then legibility takes a big hit. The best idea I had so far was to try to assign some logic to the height. For instance, below I have it based on even/odd.

```
graphGroup.selectAll('text')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', function(d) {return timeScale(d.date)-125})
    .attr('y', function(d,i) {
      if (i%2) {
        return 50-5;
      } else {
        return height/2-5;
      }
      })
    .text(function(d) {return formatTime(d.date)})
    //.attr('text-anchor','middle')
    .attr('class', 'date');
```

This worked up until a point, but with my latest data set I have 3-4 events back-to-back, so I wanted to figure out how to stagger the text vertically to make a kind of repeating stair pattern: 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3...

I tried replacing `%2` with `%3` but the result was the same. Then it dawned on me -- I somehow have to make a map of heights.

for simplicity's sake just assume:

```
var myHeightLogic: {
    h1:100,
    h2:300,
    h3:400
};
```

### Question

How can I use my `myHeightLogic` variable to calculate the right height for my text's `.attr('y', function(d,i) { })`  for a repeating staircase pattern? Would the approach be the same if I wanted to increment over 4 steps? I want to find the most scalable approach possible. It seems mathematically complicated because of the overlap between divisible numbers (for example, 6 is divisible by both 2 and 3).

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that in the `if` condition, even if you do `if (i%5)` or `if (i%10000)`, you have just **two** values: a falsy one and a truthy one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array and the index provided by the second argument with the remainder operator, as you reasoned in your question. The fact that 6 is divisible by both 2 and 3 is not a problem.

However, since you want the *"most scalable approach possible"*, you can take advantage of the fact that the domain in D3 ordinal scales, if not specified, is inferred from usage.

So, you can just do (using the new scale constructor syntax):

```
const scale = d3.scaleOrdinal([100, 300, 400])
```

And using the scale with your index.

Here is a demo:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleOrdinal([100, 300, 400]);
d3.range(20).forEach(d => {
  console.log("index: " + d + " --- position: " + scale(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And, why not, a visual representation:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const scale = d3.scaleOrdinal([0, 20, 40]);
const data = d3.range(20);
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", d => d * 30)
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("y", d => scale(d))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="50" width="600"></svg>
```